# Level Selector - Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to add 10 levels and 1 per page, which is 10 pages. How can I use this code to do that?  Right now it only has two pages. Can anyone help?

```
-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        isDragging = NO;
        lastX = 0.0f;
        xVel = 0.0f;
        contentWidth = s.width * 10.0;
        currentPage = 0;

        // main scrolling layer - add as child to this page layer.
        scrollLayer = [[[LevelScene alloc] init] autorelease];
        scrollLayer.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 1);
        scrollLayer.position = ccp(0, 0);
        [self addChild:scrollLayer];

        [self schedule:@selector(moveTick:) interval:0.02f];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) moveTick: (ccTime)dt
{
    float friction = 0.99f;
    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    if (!isDragging)
    {
        // inertia
        xVel *= friction;
        CGPoint pos = scrollLayer.position;
        pos.x += xVel;

        // to stop at bounds
        pos.x = MAX(-s.width, pos.x);
        pos.x = MIN(0, pos.x);

        if (pos.x == -s.width)
        {
            xVel = 0;
            currentPage = 1;
        }
        if (pos.x == 0)
        {
            xVel = 0;
            currentPage = 0;
        }

        // snap to page by quickly moving to it: e.g.: xVel = 40
        if (fabsf(xVel) < 10)
        {
            if (pos.x < -s.width/2.0)
            {
                xVel = -40;
            }
            else {
                xVel = 40;
            }
        }

        scrollLayer.position = pos;
    }
    else {
        xVel = (scrollLayer.position.x - lastX)/2.0;
        lastX = scrollLayer.position.x;
    }
}

- (void) ccTouchesBegan: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event
{
    isDragging = YES;
}

- (void) ccTouchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event
{
    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    // simple position update
    CGPoint a = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[touch previousLocationInView:touch.view]];
    CGPoint b = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[touch locationInView:touch.view]];
    CGPoint nowPosition = scrollLayer.position;
    nowPosition.x += (b.x - a.x);
    nowPosition.x = MAX(-s.width, nowPosition.x);
    nowPosition.x = MIN(0, nowPosition.x);
    scrollLayer.position = nowPosition;
}

- (void) ccTouchesEnded: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event
{
    isDragging = NO;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jon, it seems like you're trying to recreate a UIScrollView in cocos2d.  If that's the case, might I suggest using an existing open source project known as CCScrollLayer ([HERE](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/develop/Extensions/CCScrollLayer))  Out of the box it should do everything you need to do and is pretty easy to extend to meet your needs better.